# I can't solve a cyclic redundancy check

Tags: coding-theory

In my book there's an example of how to do a cyclic redundancy check with regular numbers.  I've tried to complete the exercise with binary numbers but without success. In the book the given polynomial equals $x^{14}+x^{12}+x^8+x^7+x^5$ and the used generator polynomial is $x^5+x^4+x^2+1$. The result of the question was $x^3+x^2+x$.

The professor included in his powerpoint that 010100011010000 is the starting message en that the remainder in binary should be 01110. The rest was up to us.

I've practiced with different binary messages and I could complete those but I got stuck on this one.

Here's what i've tried so far. When I try to convert the given polynomial into a message it has one zero more. Also my remainder is 00001 and not 01110. I wrote a program to do the calculations for me to see if i made any errors and looked online for a tool that could do it for me but both give me the same result:00001.
Whatever I do I can't seem to get the right result.
Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the polynomial division of $x^{14}+x^{12}+x^8+x^7+x^5$ by $x^5+x^4+x^2+1$ yields the remainder $x^3+x^2+x$ where the polynomials are defined over $GF(2)$.
I've checked this using SINGULAR:

> ring r = 2, (x), lp;
>
> poly f = x14+x12+x8+x7+x5;
>
> ideal i = x5+x4+x2+1;
>
> reduce(f,i);

x3+x2+x

Comment: Ok yes those were the instructions of the question. Can you also explain why when I use any online tool it gives a different answer for binary? Here's an example: Binary form: 010100011010000  divided by  110101

x**13+x**11+x**7+x**6+x**4
x**5+x**4+x**2+1

Binary form (added zeros):  01010001101000000000  divided by  110101
Result is 011010101100101
Remainder is 00001

Comment: What its the example?

Comment: Example added. Sorry for the formatting I can't press enter without actually posting a comment. I realize the polynomal provided in  my comment above is not the same as the one from the instructions but I used the string of bits that my professor included in the powerpoint. When I convert the polynomal into bits myself I also get a wrong answer:  x^14+x^12+x^8+x^7+x^5. becomes 101000110100000 and the generator is 110101 the online tool I used gives 00010 or x^1. The tool is located at: https://asecuritysite.com/comms/crc_div

Comment: I know it's not relevant to this question but I just wanted to mention that the previous  answer didn't listen, said the same (wrong?) thing fifteen times,  even when I said every source I could find disagreed with him (wikipedia, online tools that do the calculations for you, youtube videos) and then finally deleted his answer (and his account??). 10/10 answer- IGN I'll mail my professor and If he responds I will post the answer here.